# How to find difference b/w 2 dates of different formats in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, date, subtraction, epoch, iso

I have a collection in mongoDB, which contains 2 fields.
1. mongodate [ISO Date Format ]
2. createtime [ epoch milliseconds in string format ]

```
 > db.test.find()
     { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb2bbb3b278b3c384106a20"), "mongodate" : ISODate("2020-05-05T19:42:00Z"),"createtime" : "1588366164434" }
     { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb2bcabb278b3c384106a21"), "mongodate" : ISODate("2020-05-05T19:42:00Z"), "createtime" : "1588366164434" }
```

I need to find average,  min & max of (difference of mongodate & createtime)

But since the date formats of these 2 fields are different, so i am not ablle to use $substract properly. can somebody help me in this query?

Thanks,
Rahul Verma

Comment: is createTime showing milliseconds since epoch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createtime` field looks like it might be milliseconds since epoch.

You can convert the ISODate to milliseconds in an aggregation pipeline using the [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/index.html#tolong-aggregation) operator, find the difference with `$subtract`, and then use a `$group` stage with `$ave`, `$min`, and `$max` operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      epoch: {$toLong: "$mongodate"},
      createepoch: {$toLong: "$createtime"}
  }},
  {$project: {
      difference: {$subtract: [
          "$epoch",
          "$createepoch"
      ]}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: null,
      min: {$min: "$difference"},
      max: {$max: "$difference"},
      avg: {$avg: "$difference"}
  }}
])

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wVMdGLHhFpH)
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for your comment, your understaning is right, however i am not able to frame the query, could you pls help me in it? thanks in advance.